# TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html5, nodejs

Tengo el siguiente código en un servicio y me lanza el siguiente error por consola:

"
TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
at uploadImage (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\proyectosCreaDinn_Studio\codigoCompleto\api\controllers\user.js:290:35)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\proyectosCreaDinn_Studio\codigoCompleto\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\proyectosCreaDinn_Studio\codigoCompleto\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Form. (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\proyectosCreaDinn_Studio\codigoCompleto\api\node_modules\connect-multiparty\index.js:109:9)
at Form.emit (node:events:376:20)
at emitCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:10)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:79:21)
"

Al parecer el "path" no esta definido, anteriormente si me funcionaba normal pero ayer que inicie el proyecto ya me dio este error
el codigo para cargar las imagenes lo tengo asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

las funciones para devolver las imagenes las tengo asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En angular el codigo lo tengo asi para cargar la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en la plantilla de HTML5 el codigo para cargar la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien tiene alguna idea para resolver este problema.! Gracias de Antemano!

Comment: No incluyas imágenes conteniendo código.

Comment: no agregues imagen de código, así no lo podemos editar para ayudarte y deberíamos escribir todo el código y eso no lo va a querer hacer nadie XD

Comment: Ojo que el error dice que no puede leer la propiedad 'path' de `undefined`, por lo que lo que tiene valor `undefined` es `req.file.image` y no 'path'

Answer (score 1):

El problema es mas sencillo de lo que parece pero lo voy a extraer por partes para que puedas solucionarlo y de paso que el próximo error sea mas fácil de resolver
primero node te da un tipo de error:

> " TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined at uploadImage"

ahí lo que te dice es que la propiedad 'path' no esta definida.

luego te marca la linea de código donde esta afectando el error:

> (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\proyectosCreaDinn_Studio\codigoCompleto\api\controllers\user.js:290:35)

Perfecto vamos a esa linea, según la foto la linea 290 es:

```
var file_path =req.files.image.path;
```

Mo lo puedo definir con exactitud con las fotos pero como dice que es el lugar 35, el valor que no encuentra es image y como image no encuentra, la propiedad path tampoco sirve (la consola te va a mostrar path por que es lo ultimo que busca, si borras path te va a decir que el error es 'image') corri el módulo en mi máquina y me fije  la respuesta de req.files y me da el siguiente Json:

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "mensaje": {
        "imagen": {
            "fieldName": "imagen",
            "originalFilename": "124373468_1790795877751051_9034402885239572136_o.jpg",
            "path": "upload/articles/STpgYZDeu6EuUX-ghX3RJa9Q.jpg",
            "headers": {
                "content-disposition": "form-data; name=\"imagen\"; filename=\"124373468_1790795877751051_9034402885239572136_o.jpg\"",
                "content-type": "image/jpeg"
            },
            "size": 125474,
            "name": "124373468_1790795877751051_9034402885239572136_o.jpg",
            "type": "image/jpeg"
        }
    }
}
```

Como se ve en el Json anterior la propiedad que recibo por url se llama imagen
y el  código en mi caso es

```
var file_path =req.files.imagen.path;
```

Para concluir, te aparece el error por que el nombre del jSON que pasas por la reques es  distinto  a la variable que usas.

Controla el nombre del json que haces y que sea igual a el valor que va después de

```
var "file_path =req.files."
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function uploadImage(req, res){
    var userId = req.params.id;

    if(req.files){

        var file_path = req.files.image.path;
        console.log(file_path);

        var file_split = file_path.split('\\');
        console.log(file_split);

        var file_name = file_split[2];
        console.log(file_name);

        var ext_split = file_name.split('\.');
        console.log(ext_split);

        var file_ext = ext_split[1];
        console.log(file_ext);

        if(userId != req.user.sub){
            return removeFilesOfUploads(res, file_path, 'No tienes permiso para actualizar los datos del usuario');
        }

        if(file_ext == 'png' || file_ext == 'jpg' || file_ext == 'jpeg' || file_ext == 'gif'){
             
             // Actualizar documento de usuario logueado
             User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, {image: file_name}, {new:true}, (err, userUpdated) =>{
                if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error en la petición'});

                if(!userUpdated) return res.status(404).send({message: 'No se ha podido actualizar el usuario'});

                return res.status(200).send({user: userUpdated});
             });

        }else{
            return removeFilesOfUploads(res, file_path, 'Extensión no válida');
        }

    }else{
        return res.status(200).send({message: 'No se han subido imagenes'});
    }
}

function removeFilesOfUploads(res, file_path, message){
    fs.unlink(file_path, (err) => {
        return res.status(200).send({message: message});
    });
}

function getImageFile(req, res){
    var image_file = req.params.imageFile;
    var path_file = './uploads/users/'+image_file;

    fs.exists(path_file, (exists) => {
        if(exists){
            res.sendFile(path.resolve(path_file));
        }else{
            res.status(200).send({message: 'No existe la imagen...'});
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="user-image-for-edit" *ngIf="user.image">
            <img src="{{ url + 'get-image-user/' + user.image }}" alt="">
</div>
 <p>
            <label>Sube tu avatar</label>
            <input type="file" placeholder="Subir imagen"     (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)">
</p>

<input type="submit" value="{{title}}" class="btn btn-warning" [disabled]="!userEditForm.form.valid" />
```

Comment: Tus aportes no se entienden, ¿son la respuesta o parte de tu pregunta?

Comment: Si es el codigo, agregalo a tu pregunta no en la seccion de respuestas

Answer (score 0):

Tu error primero tenes que hacer esta validacion y segundo fijate que el primer split es "/" porque asi es como funcionan las paginas [www.example.com/ves/como/funciona/](http://www.example.com/ves/como/funciona/)
y el segndo es "." para separar el formato de la imagen, por eso esta mal, desde el windows es la barra al reves pero una ves que lo subis es / normal.

```
        if (req.files.file0 !== undefined) {
            var file_path = req.files.file0.path;
            var file_split = file_path.split("/");
            var file_name = file_split[2];
            var extension_split = file_name.split(".");
            var file_ext = extension_split[1];
        }
```

Comment: en tu caso en vez de "file0" es "image"